# Docker image python:3.12-alpine behaves different on Windows and Debian

Tags: python, docker, debian, alpine-linux, docker-image

I have build my Fastapi project on my Windows machine and I can successfully run it and build the image.

But when I want to run the project on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Debian 12 Bookworm with `docker --version` > `v24.0.7` it fails while telling me that it cannot find a C compiler (gcc).

It fails at the step where `pip` installs the packages from `requirements.txt`.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.12-alpine
LABEL authors="Raphael2b3"

ADD requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN rm -f ./requirements.txt

ADD . ./src

WORKDIR ./src

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
neo4j
python-dotenv
passlib
python-jose[cryptography]
passlib[bcrypt]
pytest
pytest-asyncio
pytest-order
starlette
pydantic
fastapi[all]
uvicorn[standard]
```

Error Log on Raspberry Pi with Debian 12:

```
18.55 Collecting cryptography>=3.4.0 (from python-jose[cryptography]->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
18.58   Downloading cryptography-41.0.7.tar.gz (630 kB)
18.68      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 630.9/630.9 kB 6.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
19.16   Installing build dependencies: started
33.19   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
33.23   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
33.23
33.23   × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
33.23   │ exit code: 1
33.23   ╰─> [87 lines of output]
33.23       Collecting setuptools>=61.0.0
33.23         Using cached setuptools-69.0.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
33.23       Collecting wheel
33.23         Using cached wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
33.23       Collecting cffi>=1.12
33.23         Downloading cffi-1.16.0.tar.gz (512 kB)
33.23            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 512.9/512.9 kB 4.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
33.23         Installing build dependencies: started
33.23         Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
33.23         Getting requirements to build wheel: started
33.23         Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
33.23         Installing backend dependencies: started
33.23         Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
33.23         Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
33.23         Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
33.23       Collecting setuptools-rust>=0.11.4
33.23         Downloading setuptools_rust-1.8.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.4 kB)
33.23       Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.12)
33.23         Downloading pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
33.23            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 118.7/118.7 kB 3.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
33.23       Collecting semantic-version<3,>=2.8.2 (from setuptools-rust>=0.11.4)
33.23         Downloading semantic_version-2.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
33.23       Using cached setuptools-69.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
33.23       Using cached wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
33.23       Downloading setuptools_rust-1.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
33.23       Building wheels for collected packages: cffi
33.23         Building wheel for cffi (pyproject.toml): started
33.23         Building wheel for cffi (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
33.23         error: subprocess-exited-with-error
33.23
33.23         × Building wheel for cffi (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
33.23         │ exit code: 1
33.23         ╰─> [48 lines of output]
33.23
33.23                 No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
33.23                 the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
33.23                 the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
33.23                 to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
33.23                 tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
33.23                 -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
33.23                 Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
33.23                 the IRC channel #python on irc.libera.chat.)
33.23
33.23                 Trying to continue anyway.  If you are trying to install CFFI from
33.23                 a build done in a different context, you can ignore this warning.
33.23
33.23             running bdist_wheel
33.23             running build
33.23             running build_py
33.23             creating build
33.23             creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312
33.23             creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/pkgconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/_imp_emulation.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/error.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/_shimmed_dist_utils.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             copying src/cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cffi
33.23             running build_ext
33.23             building '_cffi_backend' extension
33.23             creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-312
33.23             creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/src
33.23             creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/src/c
33.23             gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DFFI_BUILDING=1 -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/local/include/python3.12 -c src/c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/src/c/_cffi_backend.o
33.23             error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
33.23             [end of output]
33.23
33.23         note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
33.23         ERROR: Failed building wheel for cffi
33.23       Failed to build cffi
33.23       ERROR: Could not build wheels for cffi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
33.23       [end of output]
33.23
33.23   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
33.23 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
33.23
33.23 × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
33.23 │ exit code: 1
33.23 ╰─> See above for output.
33.23
33.23 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
message.txt
8 kB
```

Is there an efficient workaround and is this an issue that should be reported somewhere?

Comment: If you don't use a `...-alpine` image, can pip find precompiled wheel-format Python packages, so that it doesn't need to compile anything?

Comment: i tested it with python:3.12-slim and it has the exact same behavior

Comment: i also tried python:latest

Answer (score 0):

looks like it's trying to build the wheel for cffi. Could you try running pip install with `--no-binary` and/or `--no-index` and force it to find a wheel?

Alternately you'll have to install gcc using apt-get, which can be pretty slow to install and compile and lead to a larger image.

Also `RUN rm -f ./requirements.txt` could be removed, it unnecessarily increases the size and layers of your image.

Comment: Thank your for your answer


RUN pip install -r requirements.txt  --no-binary :none: -> same behavior

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt  --no-binary :all: (on windows) ->  error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory 


RUN pip install -r requirements.txt  --no-index -> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement neo4j (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for neo4j
Error response from daemon: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-index -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: probably just install gcc in the container since those did not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732990/installing-a-gcc-compiler-onto-a-docker-container

Comment: yes that works, but its still different behavior in the same image. Docker was invented to eliminate different behaviour. And i get another error with some rust dependencies, which i have to install aswell but only if i am on debian 12 on raspberry pi 4 hardware.

After installing gcc and cffi
The next problem i get is that pydantic requires rust to be build. so i have to install it aswell. but when trying to install it, it throws "bad systemcall"

Comment: Docker still uses the kernel of the host os, and therefore the packages installed are not hardware and os independent. The popular ones (x64, windows/linux/mac m1/mac m2) will have pre-build binaries, but in this case for the pi it is not there . If you look at something like https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files you'll see the many different builds and 1 source. So for a given system you can either install using the pre-built (fast+no compiling) or you'll need to compile from the (needs gcc, slow)

Comment: Sadly forcing pip to use prebuild binarys did not work for me. I think i am gonna look for an image with those binaries pre build. Thank you for your answer.